# Deploying MERN Stack App to AWS EC2 (Nothing happens)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mern

So I recently tried deploying my mern app onto AWS's EC2. But, after having followed all the steps to set it up, even having all the commands executing perfectly (even npm start and all) the url returns nothing(aka refuses to connect).

Here's my package.json files:

Front-End:

```
{
"name": "ems-webapp",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash.uniqueid": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^4.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^1.1.4",
    "react-cookie": "^3.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5",
    "react-strap": "0.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^6.4.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"description": "An Election Management System",
"main": "index.js",
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "ems-webapp"
},
"author": "Sushrit Pasupuleti",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {}
}
```

Back-End:

```
{
"name": "election-management-system-webapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "An Election Management App",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
},
"author": "Sushrit Pasupuleti",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^2.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.16",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.25.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
}
}
```

I first cd into client, npm install everything, then run 'npm run build' and then 'npm start' to run the client server.

Then in another shell I cd into server, npm install everything, and run 'node server.js'. All the outputs within the shell are as expected.

But when I visit my EC2 instance's public IP Address, I see nothing, it refuses to connect.

Also, just FYI, all the urls with in my app are set to localhost (3000 and 5000), should I change that or something ?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you didn't mention you web server config, one of the possible reasons that your web server (I assume nginx since it's MERN) is either not running or not configued. Can you show you `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` content?